# calling stored procedure in c# .net

Tags: .net, int

I wrote a stored procedure and executing in query without having any problem on MSSQL Server:

```
 USE [DivaReportTest]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[PR_DAILY]
        @Start = N'2012-10-16 01:00:00.000',
        @Finish = N'2012-10-18 01:00:00.000',
        @TimeRange = 1

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Calling this procedure in .NET here:

```
private DataSet GetPR_DAILY(DateTime StartTime, DateTime FinishTime, int TimeRange)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("PR_DAILY", connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = StartTime;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Finish", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = FinishTime;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeRange", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TimeRange;

            da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
```

it might be problem in SqlDbType.Int because it returns only one row int this function but when I execute in query it returns 3 rows.

Comment: How do you know it only returns one row?  It would be helpful to see the code where you are using the returned DataSet.  Also the actual stored procedure query would be useful.

Comment: I use this datasource on mschart and it shows only one bar in that chart

Comment: timerange = 1 means 1 day so there are 3 days between start and finish

Comment: Are you comparing @return_value and the count of rows in ds for how many rows that are returned? If you are then this is where your problem lies

Comment: I found the problem. My datasource has 3 rows but chart shows only the first row.
How can we fix that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems tha date format which you are passing through UI has different format. Can you please debug your through SQL profiler?

Comment: there is no problem with dates and there is no problem in procedure but it doesn't work fine when I call it from .net side